# How to animate one item when the other item is hover

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions, css-animations

I have div box which contains two items. One is under the other one. So when the lower item is hover I'd make it animated and slide it out of the top item.

```
<div id="main">
        <div id="box"></div>
        <div id="item"></div>
</div>
```

With my knowledge in CSS3 I could only make a transition for item to slide it out in hover. But I want it happen when #main is hover not #item. 
Have a look at the them please.
http://jsfiddle.net/sL3Pw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, there is no way currently to style a parent element of a child in pure CSS. You can use JavaScript as a way to achieve the desired effect.

#### (UPDATE)

You can achieve this in JavaScript by doing the following (DEMO: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yYJZz/))

#### JS

This should run onload or else it will not work.

```
// On Hover
document.getElementById('main').onmouseover = function () {
    document.getElementById('item').classList.add("to-left"); // Add To Left Class
}

// OnMouseOut (Not Hover)
document.getElementById('main').onmouseout = function () {
    document.getElementById('item').classList.remove("to-left"); // Remove To Left Class
}
```

Please remember to change the IDs of the elements if needed.

#### CSS

Add this CSS class to your CSS

```
.to-left {
    margin-left: 60px;
}
```

And your HTML stays the same. This should get what I believe your desired result is. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your post. Can explain more please how to do it by JS ?!

Comment: Not a problem. I will spin up a demo.

Comment: @KamranJafari - I have updated my answer to show you how to do this in JavaScript.